# How to Retrieve an ID from One Google Sheets Table Based on Date Comparison with Another Table

Tags: google-sheets, indexing, google-sheets-formula, match, vlookup

I have two tables in Google Sheets and I need to retrieve an ID based on a date column. Table 1 has the monthly sales data while table 2 has the information if a store is open or closed for a given date.
*If the store has closed then Closing will have data, otherwise is blank (store is not closed).*

So basically, both tables have the same structures: Name, ID, and Date columns.

Table 1)

| Name | ID | Date Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A |  | 1/1/2000 |
| A |  | 1/1/2005 |
| B |  | 1/1/2000 |
| B |  | 1/1/2005 |
| B |  | 1/1/2023 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| A |  | 1/1/2023 |

Table 2)

| Name | ID | Closing |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1/1/2005 |
| A | 2 |  |
| B | 3 | 1/1/2008 |
| A | 4 |  |

What I want is that if **Date Sales** is less than **Closing**, then the first **ID** from *Table 2* should be retrieved in **ID** for *Table 1*.

The result should be something like:

| Name | ID | Date Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1/1/2000 |
| A | 2 | 1/1/2005 |
| B | 3 | 1/1/2000 |
| B | 3 | 1/1/2005 |
| B | 4 | 1/1/2023 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| A | 2 | 1/1/2023 |

I think this can be done with a combination of VLOOKUP, INDEX, and MATCH. However, my formula so far is not able to retrieve the correct ID for the given date.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You second table doesn't have closing date for 2nd row. Then how ID is 2 for 2nd row?

Comment: @Harun24hr "If the store has close then Closing will have data, otherwise is blank." If the store is not closed then closing will be blank. This means the store has the same legal name, but relocated.

Comment: are there going to be *multiple closing dates* for a single name(*store*)?!

Comment: @rockinfreakshow No, normally 1 closing, not multiple coincidences. The thing is that it's not that common to happen, but there are 5 stores that show this behavior. Since they are relocated or changed owners then the contract is new. Furthermore, a new ID is generated, nonetheless the store name remains the same. 
The problem is that not matching them properly can make me report a store with the actual same name as having sales but when you analyze by ID, happens to be a closed store. This is because VLOOKUP returns the first match.

Comment: So Far I've tried this (Legal would be Table 2, column A is Name, Column B is ID and column AI is closing. On my actual sheet, that's will be table 1 I have column U that's the Date sales and B that's Name) 

=IFERROR(IF(U2703 < INDEX(Legal!AI:AI,MATCH(B2703,Legal!A:A,0)),INDEX(Legal!B:B,MATCH(B2703,Legal!A:A,2)),INDEX(Legal!B:B,MATCH(B2703,Legal!A:A,0)+1)),"")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using `Xlookup function` :

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(XLOOKUP((C2:C25)+1,C$29:C$32,B$29:B$32,,1))
```

*Note: Adjust the range according to your data*

`C2:C25` range is for the data sales , I add plus 1 so that the date will be included for the previous ID.

`C29:C32` range is for the closing dates

`B29:B32` is for the IDs

**RESULT:**
[image]

Comment: This one worked, however I needed to change a few things since data was actually in two different sheets

Comment: I'm glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=map(A2:A,C2:C,lambda(a,c,if(or(a="",c=""),,ifna(let(Σ,filter(F:G,E:E=a), xlookup(c+1,index(Σ,,2),index(Σ,,1),+filter(index(Σ,,1),index(Σ,,2)=""),1))))))
```

[image]